# How to get a list of installed packages held back from upgrade?

Tags: package-management

Recently, I needed to get a list of packages that were installed on my Ubuntu system which were also put on hold for upgrade.

The 'hold' status for a package means that when the operating system is upgraded, the installer will not upgrade these packages either, unless explicitly stated in the options.

I am looking for a command-line solution but understand this may be possible from the GUI as well.

Comment: there are different options to do that... most of them are also listed at https://askubuntu.com/a/18656/354350.

Comment: To unhold all held packages: `sudo apt-mark unhold $(apt-mark showhold)`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can use `apt-mark`:

```
apt-mark showhold
```

this will show the packages that are kept in "hold" state so that the pacakge manager won't auto upgrade the packages.

From `man apt-mark`:

```
showhold
           showhold is used to print a list of packages on hold
```

Comment: Shows nothing but system is complaining about held packages. Must be more fundamental way.

Comment: just upgraded to, then did a fresh install of xubuntu 20.04.1 desktop.  I have the same experience -->   " lib32z1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."  apt-mark showhold returns null

Answer (score 25):

Use dpkg

```
dpkg -l | grep "^hi"
```

The `-l` means to list all packages which are then piped into grep.

The regular expression `"^hi"` means to search for all lines that begin with "hi" which are initials for "hold" and "installed".

By default, `dpkg -l` will list the status, package name, version, architecture, and a short description.

Comment: This method works on debian systems regardless of the higher level package wrapper being used, thus it is more general.

Comment: for inspecting my system when something fishy is going on `dpkg -l | grep --invert-match "^ii"` helped me every now and then. - this lists all packages which are not just installed as they should be.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy: I, too, did find lots of packages with status `ri` instead of `ii`. Every one of those was fixed with `sudo apt install --reinstall package-name`. Do you know what might cause these problems?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen at the top of the output of `dpkg -l` you've got a little explanation of the output... `ii` means the package is currently **i**nstalled (2nd letter) and it should stay **i**nstalled (1st letter). `ri` means that the package is currently **i**nstalled (2nd letter) and should be **r**emoved/uninstalled (1st letter) but keep configuration. - so i'm not sure what you are "fixing". **||** real errors would be indicated through a 3rd letter or i would also investigate a little bit more if the 2nd letter is for instance a `F` or a `H`.

Comment: Why would a package enter state `ri` when I haven't requested the package to be removed?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen well... this finally exceeds the scope of comments to a more or less unrelated question/answer (perhaps a separate question with more detailed information would be reasonable), but i guess dependencies...? :-D

Comment: ...this is also a reason why most of the time average users should use Synaptic, apt or aptitude instead of dpkg, if not a completely simple package manager resp. app store by their distribution.

Comment: I forked the new question to https://askubuntu.com/q/1352226/50254

Answer (score 7):

as an alternative you can also use `dpkg --get-selections`:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "\<hold$"
```

`dpkg --get-selections` lists the status of all installed packages and `grep "\<hold$"` only shows lines which end with the word "hold".

perhaps also interesting, if you are looking for irregularities - especially if the above shows nothing (useful), would be

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep --invert-match "\<install$"
```

this shows all lines/packages which are not just installed.

Answer (score 2):

In apt-mark versions > 2.4 you have to use the following command:

```
apt-mark showhold
```

Also it is an old tool **aptitude** does a fine job on the command line and you can easily surf through the hold packages:

```
aptitude
```

Type <kbd>u</kbd> to update packages and then press <kbd>g</kbd> and you will see the held back packages.

Answer (score 1):

***And*** to unhold all held packages, use

`sudo apt-mark unhold $(apt-mark showhold)`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I landed here because I was searching for how to unhold  packages. Feel free to delete my answer and those people landed here for the same reason will still be at lost. This is not to answer the question as the top one has already done so. Moreover, the reason people need to find out the held packages is most probably to unhold them. My answer just save them to find the how to for the next step.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.